# Install4j cannot find Java runtime environment after un-bundling JRE

Tags: install4j

Lately, we changed our Install4j installation mechanize in that we won't bundle an inner JRE anymore, but the customer has to supply a link to it.
When he do so, we take the supplied path and define a new custom environment variable to it.

Actions we did:

- In Media -> Windows -> Bundled JRE -> We set it to '*Don't bundle a JRE*'
- In 'General Settings' -> JRE Search Sequence -> we removed the previous '*Java_Home*' enviroment variable and set a new custom one in which we use to link to the external JRE path the customer supplies.

When the Install4j start we are getting an error **that the wizard cannot find a java runtime environment**.

When observing the temp log, it looks like it tries to find the java.exe under the executor folder and not using the custom env variable.

What could cause the problem?
Is the fact that '*Registry and standard locations*' option available under the '*JRE Search Sequence*' could be related?

**Attached the screenshot of JRE search sequence and the native log**:

[image]

**Log**:

```
Started executable C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX Risk Management\ETL\etl_executor.exe at Mon Feb 17 14:59:22 2020

[0:0] restrict DLL directories
[0:10] init file name C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX Risk Management\ETL\etl_executor.exe C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX Risk Management\ETL\etl_executor.exe 73 0
[0:10] number of sections: 6
[0:11] size of optional headers: 240
[0:11] resSectionTableStart: 720
[0:11] rawDataSize: 2560, rawDataOffset: 452608
[0:12] sun.locale.formatasdefault is false
[0:12] language/country is en_US
[0:13] change working directory to C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX Risk Management\ETL
[0:16] single instance mode
[0:16] semaphore name Local\c:_program_files_XXX_XXX_risk_management_etl_etl_executor.exe, code 0, value 00000000000000CC
[0:16] Init done
[0:57] Starting work
[0:88] number of sections: 6
[0:88] size of optional headers: 240
[0:104] resSectionTableStart: 720
[0:104] rawDataSize: 2560, rawDataOffset: 452608
[0:104] starting at 455168
[0:104] verifying integrity length 3500065
[0:182] checksums: 2993458205 2993458205 -1301509091 -1301509091
[0:182] tempPath is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\
[0:182] tempFile is C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp
[0:182] Temp dir3: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363
[0:182] native lib dir is ${launcher:sys.launcherTempDirectory}\user
[0:182] expanding2 ${launcher:sys.launcherTempDirectory} to C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363 in C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user.
[0:182] Adding DLL directory C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user
[0:182] Setting PATH (native libs) C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Perforce;C:\Program Files\Perforce\DVCS\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;%CX_JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
[0:182] extracting files
[0:182] Included files: 15
[0:182] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4jruntime.jar (size: 1764884)
[0:182] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_4_1llfbrx_1x5khvr.png (size: 2419)
[0:182] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_5_1llfbrx_18gg8kx@2x.png (size: 15419)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4jparams.conf (size: 141906)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_5_1llfbrx_18gg8kx.png (size: 9202)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\MessagesDefault (size: 33730)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_0_1llfbrx.utf8 (size: 33730)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_1_1llfbrx_7760vr.png (size: 3593)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\stats.properties (size: 254)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_3_1llfbrx_vxu3xo.png (size: 1442)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user.jar (size: 53933)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\installer.ico (size: 13430)
[0:198] creating directory C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user\mssql-jdbc-6.4.0.jre8.jar (size: 905963)
[0:198] creating directory C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\user\sqljdbc_auth.dll (size: 299088)
[0:198] extracting C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\i4j_extf_2_1llfbrx.jpg (size: 42315)
[0:213] extracting files done
[0:213] Current working dir: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363
[0:213] Full JRE path: C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1\e4jCDB2.tmp_dir1581944363\jre.tar.gz
[0:213] No JRE included
[0:213] LoadDLL (0, (null), 0)
[0:213] Searching for a JVM
[0:213] MinVersion: 1.8, MaxVersion: 
[0:213] Testing location  (type Y)
[0:213] Testing location CX_JAVA_HOME (type E)
[0:213] Testing location JDK_HOME (type E)
[0:213] checking app id allinstdirs9791-3088-5353-5236 (0, FFFFFFFF80000001)
[0:213] could not open installation node 2
[0:213] checking app id allinstdirs9791-3088-5353-5236 (256, FFFFFFFF80000001)
[0:213] could not open installation node 2
[0:213] checking app id allinstdirs9791-3088-5353-5236 (0, FFFFFFFF80000002)
[0:213] could not open installation node 2
[0:213] checking app id allinstdirs9791-3088-5353-5236 (256, FFFFFFFF80000002)
[0:213] could not open installation node 2
[0:213] Search sequence finished
[0:213] ERROR: No JVM found
[0:213] Download location:
```

Comment: Please share a screenshot of the config of your JRE search sequence as well as the native log produced by running the installer with the argument `/create-i4j-log`.

Comment: @IngoKegel - thanks. I attached a screenshot & the native log.
A point I wish to emphasize - not only we are not bundling the inner JRE anymore, but on the customer's side it's not necessarily have to be a JDK installed. the Install4j should run with the env variable of the JRE which now is a prerequisite. When I choose 'Locate' and choose the JAVA.EXE inside the JRE/BIN, it's working...

Comment: In the log it says, `Testing location CX_JAVA_HOME`, does the file %CX_JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll exist? What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: We are using 7.0.12 version.
The file %CX_JAVA_HOME%\bin\server\jvm.dll exist do exists

Comment: Please try with 8.0.4, there have been fixes regarding the detection of OpenJDK JREs in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks checking out. Do we have to upgrade our license to 8.0.4 version? No way to push these fixes to version 7 as well?

Comment: There is no further development on 7.x. I would first try with 8.0.4 to check if that indeed solves this problem.

Comment: @IngoKegel I've run in to similar problems with AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.6. My problem is resolved by using 8.0.4. However, that would require purchasing a new licens. Is there no backporting of this type of bugs?